# Finding a point in an STFT plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I have the short term fourier plot of a voltage/time waveform on which I have applied a bandpass filter with passband 2.5k-3kHz - the frequencies which cause this bump:
[image: curve]

This is the stft plot which I plotted using matplotlib's [pcolormesh()](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) function.
Here the shading is selected as 'gouraud':
[image: gouraud_stft]

**Is there any way to find the point which forms a line at a little before 0.0018 sec?**

Looking at the stft plot when shading is selected as 'flat', this is the result:
[image: flat_stft]

Looking at this, I think the line in gouraud shading is the left border of the green block. But I have to do this for multiple waveforms - finding when the curve starts to form. **Is there any way to do this from the stft plot?** That way, I can have the relevant frequencies as well.

Here is how I plot the stft: (sampleFreq, segmentTimes, and stftX are returned by [scipy.signal.stft()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html))

```
# function to plot stft
def plotSTFT(sampleFreq, segmentTimes, stftX):
    plt.pcolormesh(segmentTimes, sampleFreq, np.abs(stftX), shading='gouraud')
    plt.ylabel("Frequency (Hz)")
    plt.xlabel("Time (s)")
    plt.title("Sort Term FFT")
    plt.show()
```

And this is what np.abs(stftX) looks like:

```
[[3.70210968e-03 7.15446518e-04 7.19726916e-03 ... 3.86722138e-03
  1.17172997e-04 1.27395888e-09]
 [3.15837680e-03 2.16981103e-03 4.32806937e-03 ... 2.52695497e-03
  1.09094551e-04 1.27369563e-09]
 [2.00026090e-03 4.65750719e-04 6.91940091e-04 ... 6.14402287e-04
  7.70236881e-05 1.27290625e-09]
 ...
 [3.88944093e-05 1.29308926e-10 4.25956899e-11 ... 7.13448070e-11
  1.41328412e-07 4.26490154e-10]
 [3.88856011e-05 6.46192014e-11 4.08120336e-11 ... 3.62114678e-11
  1.41283187e-07 4.26353366e-10]
 [3.88826928e-05 7.96805222e-13 4.02009003e-11 ... 7.32729719e-12
  1.41291340e-07 4.26307683e-10]]
```